# Symfony2 acces doctrine in entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

There is my entity:

## Entity

```
namespace Catalog\WebBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class ComCompany
{

    private $entityManager;

    public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function getCmpCategory()
    {
         return  $customer = $this
                ->entityManager
                ->getRepository('CatalogWebBundle:ComCategory')
                ->findOneBycmpCat('123123');
    }


}
```

## Services.yml

```
services:
catalog_web.comcompany:
    class: Catalog\WebBundle\Entity\ComCompany
    calls:
        - [ setEntityManager, [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]]
```

I'm getting error:

*InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "catalog_web.comcompany" (in /home/katalogas/domains/ekatalogas.eu/public_html/src/Catalog/WebBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/services.yml). Looked for namespace "catalog_web.comcompany", found none*

I'm not understant what problam is in services.yml configuration file.

Comment: note that you are doing it wrong. Entity is meant to be only definition of Entity and have no logic. This ``getCmpCategory`` method should be places in RepositoryClass - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Comment: Yep.  Makes no sense to define an entity as a service.  Doctrine 2 knows nothing about the service container.  Though the error message is puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

Your .yml have wrong spacing. It should be:

```
services:
   catalog_web.comcompany:
      class: Catalog\WebBundle\Entity\ComCompany
      calls:
          - [ setEntityManager, [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]]
```

Comment: That was just a copy/paste thing.  I'm sure his services.yml has the right indentation.  Someday I need to figure out how to paste in code with leading spaces.

Comment: I aggre. Reason is define enity as service.

Comment: @PiotrGalas How to define entity as service I nothing found about this in Symfony documention can you show example ?

Comment: this is because you SHOULD NOT define entity as a service

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski plesase short example how to define entity as service.

Comment: ehh, you **SHOULD NOT** define entity as a service. It means there is **NO** example of it becuase **NO** one does that and symfony **DOES NOT** support this.